# How to load the .run before the controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm doing an app in Cordova using a pre-populated db, I'm trying to put the result of a db search in a < select > but without using a ng-click in my html file (that is the only way I found so far to solve the problem) I tried with ng-init but it executes the function in my controller before the .run that is where I load my db, here is the code.

app.js

```
var ionicApp = angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'ngCordova']);
var db = null;

ionicApp.run(function($ionicPlatform, $cordovaSQLite) {
 $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
  if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
   cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);

   cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
  }
  if(window.StatusBar) {
    StatusBar.styleDefault();
  }
    window.plugins.sqlDB.copy("mydb.db","./plugins/me.rahul.plugins.sqlDB/WWW/sqlDB.js",function() { 
      db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB("mydb.db");
    }, function(error) {
       db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB("mydb.db");
    });
  });
});

ionicApp.controller('first-select', function($scope, $cordovaSQLite){
  $scope.options = [];
  $scope.select = function () {
    var query = "SELECT emp FROM adm_cia";
    $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query,[]).then(function(res){
      if(res.rows.length > 0){
        var newOptions = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < res.rows.length; i++){
          var idn = (i+1).toString();
          newOptions.push({id: idn, name: res.rows.item(i).emp});
         }
      $scope.options = newOptions;
      } else {    }
    }, function(error){
  });
 }
})
```

and the index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
        <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/mobile-angular-ui/dist/css/mobile-angular-ui-base.min.css"/>
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/angular-aside/docs/js/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/mobile-angular-ui/dist/js/mobile-angular-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
        <script src="js/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>
        <script src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
        <title>Login</title>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="starter" ng-controller="first-select" class="scrollable-content" ng-init="select()">
        <form id="login" method="get" action="indice.html">
            <div align="justify">
                <h1 class="color-letra">Nova Plus mobile</h1>
                <div class="form_input">
                    <input ng-click="select()" type="text" placeHolder="Ususario" name="username" requiered> <!-- this ng-click will be instead of the ng-init and is the only way that it works-->
                </div>
                <div class="form_input">
                    <input type="password" placeHolder="Contraseña" name="password" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form_input" style="margin-bottom : 30px">
                    <select name="empresas" class="empresas" required>
                        <option value="">Seleccione empresa</option>
                        <option value="1">prueba</option>
                        <option ng-repeat="option in options" value="{{option.id}}">{{option.name}}</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="centrar">
                    <button type="submit" id="btn-default">Enviar</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
 </html>
```

this code will do the select() function first and after it will open the database, the idea is that it first open the database and after do the select() function.

Regards.

Comment: This should already be happening. Did you copy/paste this  code? Because your line `db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB(mydb.db");` is missing a `"`. Other than that, this looks correct.

Comment: I misspelled that but just here in the code is correct. @matthewpavkov

Comment: Is `window.plugins.sqlDB.copy` synchronous? It looks like the function are in a callback, which may imply they're async.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$ionicPlatform.ready` is not the first thing to be executed in your ionic application. The `$ionicPlatform.ready` function is called to tell you that the cordova APIs are ready to be used (it is a wrapper for the cordova deviceReady event). This means that Angular will start bootstrapping your app as soon as the library is loaded without waiting for the `$ionicPlatform.ready` callback.

You can fix this by removing the `ng-app="starter"` tag from your html body declaration as this instructs angular to immediately bootstrap your application. And instead bootstrap the application manually after `ionic.Platform.ready` is fired and you have done all of your initialisation. Here a sample code

```
var ionicApp = angular.module('starter', ['ionic']);

ionicApp.controller('first-select', function($scope){
  $scope.select = function(){
    console.log("controller initialized");
    //  do your thing
  };
})

ionic.Platform.ready(function() {
  console.log("device ready!");

  // do your db init magic 

  angular.bootstrap(document.body, ['starter']);
});
```

This way, "device ready" log will always be written to the console before "controller initialised" log, and there will be no race conditions.

Note that you can't use the run block of the ionicApp module to bootstrap your application, because the run block is called after angular has bootstrapped the application. So if you have not bootstrapped it automatically it will never be called.

Comment: you were right, now I'm having a problem with $cordovaSQLite.openDB("mydb.db"); I don't know why it doesn't open the data base but thank you for your help was really really useful!