# $location.path won't work on iOS after login

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Developing my first Ionic app. Testing locally in the browser everything is working as is, but when I test on my iOS device (v9.2.1) $location.path(...) does not seem to work and the page/state stays where it is.

Process flow is:
1. User enters login details in form
2. User is validated using my external API
3. Successful response registers the device for push
4. User is directed to main app page

I am receiving the console logs at each step so I can see that everything is working up until that point. I do not get any errors in the console (looking in xcode and safari).

Code (I've removed some form validation for email, password check to simplify):

```
.controller('LoginController', function($scope, $http, $state, $ionicPopup, $localstorage, $location, $ionicLoading, $ionicPush, $timeout) {
$scope.data = {};

$http.post(api_path+'validateUser', JSON.stringify({key: 'xxx', email: $scope.data.email, password: $scope.data.password})).success(function(data) {
    $ionicLoading.show();
    console.log(data);
    if (data.result === 1) {
        console.log('successfully logged in');
        if ($localstorage.get('storage_user_id') !== data.user_data.id) {
            $localstorage.clear();
            console.log('clearing storage');
        }
        $localstorage.set('storage_user_id', data.user_data.id);
        $localstorage.setObject('user_data', data.user_data);
        $ionicLoading.hide();

        if (!registeredPush) {
            registeredPush = true;
            $ionicPush.register();
            console.log('registering push');
        }

        console.log(data.user_data.signature);
        if (data.user_data.signature === '') {
            console.log('Going to signatures page');
            $location.path('/save-signature');
        } else {
            console.log('Going to buildings page');
            $location.path('/app/buildings');
        }
    }
});
```

I have tried using:
$state.go(...); $scope.apply etc.

ionic info:

```
Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 5.3.3
Gulp version:  CLI version 3.9.0
Gulp local:   Local version 3.9.0
Ionic Version: 1.1.0
Ionic CLI Version: 1.7.12
Ionic App Lib Version: 0.6.5
ios-deploy version: 1.8.4 
ios-sim version: 5.0.4 
OS: Mac OS X El Capitan
Node Version: v0.12.2
Xcode version: Xcode 7.2 Build version 7C68
```

Thanks.

Comment: I have just tried setting: **ionic config set dev_push true** and the redirect now works on the device. Any idea why **ionic config set dev_push false** would stop location path from working?

Comment: what is your output?

Comment: @BIU the normal output in the xcode build is the same if dev_push is true or false, apart from 1 extra line at the end when dev_push is false: **Ionic Core: plugins are ready**

Comment: I mean your console log - do you get "Going to signatures page"?

Comment: Right sorry, yes I get that output - but in this case it's going to the buildings page. Perhaps my issue is with the push notification. In my main app controller I am calling the $ionicPush.init(...) function, but I wonder if this should be in app.js under $ionicPlatform.ready. I just don't know how to share information between the files so I can do an ajax call when a device is registered (to save the token)

Comment: ionicPush.init() should definitely be within $ionicPlatform.ready.  You share information the same way as any angular app - through services. (you don't technically need to here, but it would be cleaner).  you can set the app up to call ionicPush on ready(), and in the success function there, send the received token to another function/service to save on your server.

Comment: how any of that has any bearing on $location.path though, i don't know - unless that's also being called before the $ionicPlatform.ready()

Comment: Fun fact, if you init your ionic app using ng-app="myApp" then your controllers code will be called before $ionicPlatform.ready() is called. Please check my answer here for details 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34749202/how-to-load-the-run-before-the-controller/34751877#34751877

Comment: Don't want this discussion to run on too long in comments - but removing calls to register push and the app works normally with dev_push set to false. So definitely something wrong with how I've setup push. Will post when resolved. Thanks for your help BIU

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Hisham Abdel-Hafez, your comment put me on the right track to solving this.

As he mentioned the $ionicPlatform.ready() method is called before the the plugins are ready. I noticed this in the xcode output that I was never getting the output **Ionic Core: plugins are ready** unless I removed everything inside my ready function (keyboard and status bar settings) and also removed the **$urlRouterProvider.otherwise** for the default page.

The reason location path was not working when I tried to register push was because everything was happening before the plugins were all actually ready and I guess that caused a JS error to halt my app.

What this also exposed to me now is my main application controller is called only after my login page controller, so I still need to refine my code and get the hang of Angular and Ionic.